# Why is camera's position not correctly calculated (canvas)

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

I am  making a clone of agar.io and I am stuck in my code. I can't understand why my camera's position is not correctly calculated. I want my camera's position to half the vector between the farthest blob and the closest blob.

Below is a picture and my code:

[image]

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Play Agario Clone</title>

 <style>
 body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="game">
  kindly update your browser.
 </canvas>

 <script>
 var 
 canvas, 
 ctx, 
 width = innerWidth, 
 height = innerHeight,
 mouseX = 0,
 mouseY = 0;

 var

 camera = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,

  // camera
  update: function(obj) {
   var farthestBlobX = Math.max.apply(0, obj.blobs.map(function(cell) { return cell.x }));
   var farthestBlobY = Math.max.apply(0, obj.blobs.map(function(cell) { return cell.y }));
   var closestBlobX = Math.min.apply(0, obj.blobs.map(function(cell) { return cell.x }));
   var closestBlobY = Math.min.apply(0, obj.blobs.map(function(cell) { return cell.y }));
   var x = farthestBlobX - closestBlobX;
   var y = farthestBlobY - closestBlobY;
   var length = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

   this.x = length/2 - width/2;
   this.y = length/2 - height/2;
  }
 },

 player = {
  defaultMass: 54,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  blobs: [],

  update: function () {
   for (var i = 0; i < this.blobs.length; i ++) {
    var x = mouseX + camera.x - this.blobs[i].x;
    var y = mouseY + camera.y - this.blobs[i].y;
    var length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
    var speed = 54/this.blobs[i].mass;
    
    this.blobs[i].velX = x/length * speed * Math.min(1, Math.pow(x / this.blobs[i].mass, 2));
    this.blobs[i].velY = y/length * speed * Math.min(1, Math.pow(x / this.blobs[i].mass, 2));

    this.blobs[i].x += this.blobs[i].velX;
    this.blobs[i].y += this.blobs[i].velY;

    for (var j = 0; j < this.blobs.length; j ++) {
     if (j != i && this.blobs[i] !== undefined) {
            var blob1 = this.blobs[i];
            var blob2 = this.blobs[j];
            var x = blob2.x - blob1.x;
            var y = blob2.y - blob1.y;
            var dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

            if (dist < blob1.mass + blob2.mass) {
              x /= dist;
              y /= dist;
              blob1.x = blob2.x - x * (blob1.mass + blob2.mass);
              blob1.y = blob2.y - y * (blob1.mass + blob2.mass);
            }
          }
    }
   }

   this.x += (mouseX - width/2)/(width/2) * 1;
   this.y += (mouseY - height/2)/(height/2) * 1
  },

  split: function (cell) {
   cell.mass /= 2;

   this.blobs.push({
    x: cell.x,
    y: cell.y,
    mass: cell.mass
   });
  },

  draw: function () {
   for (var i = 0; i < this.blobs.length; i ++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(-camera.x + this.blobs[i].x, -camera.y + this.blobs[i].y, this.blobs[i].mass, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
   }
  }
 };

 function handleMouseMove (e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
 }

 function setup () {
  canvas = document.getElementById("game");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;

  addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);

  player.blobs.push({
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   mass: player.defaultMass
  });
  player.blobs.push({
   x: 100,
   y: 100,
   mass: player.defaultMass/2
  });
  player.blobs.push({
   x: 100,
   y: 100,
   mass: player.defaultMass*2
  });

  var loop = function () {
   update();
   draw();
   requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
 }

 function update () {
  camera.update(player);
  player.update();
 }

 function draw () {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

  player.draw();
 }

 setup();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer the camera to have the average position of all the blobs? something like: `camera.x = (player.blobs[0].x + player.blobs[1].x ... + player.blobs[n].x) / player.blobs.length` (pseudo code).

Comment: no its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there is an answer already..

```js
var canvas;
var ctx;
var width = innerWidth;
var height = innerHeight;
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

const camera = {
    x : 0,
    y : 0,
    update(obj) { // camera
        this.x = (obj.blobsExtent.minx + obj.blobsExtent.maxx) / 2;
        this.y = (obj.blobsExtent.miny + obj.blobsExtent.maxy) / 2;
        this.x -= width / 2;
        this.y -= height / 2;
    }
};

const player = {
    defaultMass : 54,
    blobs : [],
    blobsExtent : { // get the extent while updating the blobs save you having to iterate all the objects a second time to get extent
        minx :0,
        miny : 0,
        maxx : 0,
        maxy : 0,
    },
    update  () {
        var be = this.blobsExtent; // be for Blob Extent alias to save typing and make code easier to read
        for (var i = 0; i < this.blobs.length; i++) {
            var blob1 = this.blobs[i];
            var x = mouseX - blob1.x;
            var y = mouseY - blob1.y;
            // to stop the divide by zero propigating NaN set length to 1 if less than 1
            var length = Math.max(1,Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)); // x * x is quicker than Math.pow(x,2)
            var speed = 54 / blob1.mass;

            blob1.velX = x / length * speed * Math.min(1, Math.pow(x / blob1.mass, 2));
            blob1.velY = y / length * speed * Math.min(1, Math.pow(x / blob1.mass, 2));

            blob1.x += blob1.velX;
            blob1.y += blob1.velY;

            for (var j = 0; j < this.blobs.length; j++) {
                if (j != i) {
                    var blob2 = this.blobs[j];
                    var x = blob2.x - blob1.x;
                    var y = blob2.y - blob1.y;
                    var dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
                    var radTotal = blob1.mass + blob2.mass;

                    if (dist < radTotal) {
                        x /= dist;
                        y /= dist;
                        blob1.x = blob2.x - x * radTotal;
                        blob1.y = blob2.y - y * radTotal;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(i === 0){ // use first blob to setup min max
                be.maxx = be.minx = blob1.x;
                be.maxy = be.miny = blob1.y;
            }else{
                be.maxx = Math.max(be.maxx, blob1.x);
                be.maxy = Math.max(be.maxy, blob1.y);
                be.minx = Math.min(be.minx, blob1.x);
                be.miny = Math.min(be.miny, blob1.y);
            }
        }
    },
    split (cell) {
        cell.mass /= 2;
        this.blobs.push(createBlob(cell.x, cell.y, cell.mass));
    },
    draw () {
        var b;  // alias for blob
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";  // all the same colour then can render as one path
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,-camera.x,-camera.y);
        ctx.beginPath();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.blobs.length; i++) {
            b = this.blobs[i];
            ctx.arc( b.x, b.y, b.mass, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.closePath();
        }
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // restore default transform
    }
};

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX + camera.x;
    mouseY = e.clientY + camera.y;
}
function createBlob(x,y,mass){ return {x,y,mass} }
function setup() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    player.blobs.push(createBlob(0,0,player.defaultMass));
    player.blobs.push(createBlob(100,100,player.defaultMass / 2));
    player.blobs.push(createBlob(100,100,player.defaultMass * 2));
}

function update() {
    camera.update(player);
    player.update();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    player.draw();
}    
function loop() {
    update();
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}


setup();
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
 body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
```

```html
<canvas id="game"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of computing everything relative to your camera, use your camera to set the global transformation matrix of your canvas, and only for this.
This way, your blobs' updates will be cleaner, and your camera easier to manage.

Now to get the middle position between two points, do `(pt1 + pt2) / 2`.
You were not clear in your question, if `fartherstX` and `fartherstY` should represent the same `blob`. In your code it wasn't, so I didn't change it.

Also, I didn't gone into all your logics, but beware NaN values, I got some while doing the edit.

```js
function draw() {
  var cw = ctx.canvas.width / 2;
  var ch = ctx.canvas.height / 2;
  // reset transform to clear the canvas
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  // here we really set the camera position
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, -camera.x + cw, -camera.y + ch);
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height); // just to show the original area
  player.draw();
}

var
  canvas,
  ctx,
  width = innerWidth,
  height = innerHeight,
  mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0;

var camera = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,

    // camera
    update: function(obj) {
      var farthestBlobX = Math.max.apply(0, obj.blobs.map(function(cell) {
        return cell.x
      }));
      var farthestBlobY = Math.max.apply(0, obj.blobs.map(function(cell) {
        return cell.y
      }));
      var closestBlobX = Math.min.apply(0, obj.blobs.map(function(cell) {
        return cell.x
      }));
      var closestBlobY = Math.min.apply(0, obj.blobs.map(function(cell) {
        return cell.y
      }));
      this.x = (closestBlobX + farthestBlobX) / 2 || 0;
      this.y = (closestBlobY + farthestBlobY) / 2 || 0;
    }
  },

  player = {
    defaultMass: 54,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    blobs: [],

    update: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.blobs.length; i++) {
        var x = mouseX - this.blobs[i].x || 0;
        var y = mouseY - this.blobs[i].y || 0;
        var length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
        var speed = 54 / this.blobs[i].mass;

        this.blobs[i].velX = x / length * speed * Math.min(1, Math.pow(x / this.blobs[i].mass, 2));
        this.blobs[i].velY = y / length * speed * Math.min(1, Math.pow(x / this.blobs[i].mass, 2));

        this.blobs[i].x += this.blobs[i].velX;
        this.blobs[i].y += this.blobs[i].velY;

        for (var j = 0; j < this.blobs.length; j++) {
          if (j != i && this.blobs[i] !== undefined) {
            var blob1 = this.blobs[i];
            var blob2 = this.blobs[j];
            var x = blob2.x - blob1.x;
            var y = blob2.y - blob1.y;
            var dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

            if (dist < blob1.mass + blob2.mass) {
              x /= dist;
              y /= dist;
              blob1.x = blob2.x - x * (blob1.mass + blob2.mass);
              blob1.y = blob2.y - y * (blob1.mass + blob2.mass);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      this.x += (mouseX - width / 2) / (width / 2) * 1;
      this.y += (mouseY - height / 2) / (height / 2) * 1;
    },

    split: function(cell) {
      cell.mass /= 2;

      this.blobs.push({
        x: cell.x,
        y: cell.y,
        mass: cell.mass
      });
    },

    draw: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.blobs.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.blobs[i].x, this.blobs[i].y, this.blobs[i].mass, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  };

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
}

function setup() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("game");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;

  addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);

  player.blobs.push({
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    mass: player.defaultMass
  });
  player.blobs.push({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    mass: player.defaultMass / 2
  });
  player.blobs.push({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    mass: player.defaultMass * 2
  });

  var loop = function() {
    update();
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function update() {
  camera.update(player);
  player.update();
}

setup();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="game">kindly update your browser.</canvas>
```

Comment: I think I figured out the problem as you said farthest x and y should be of same blob.