# Why circles aren't separated properly

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have this code for separating two circles. the problem is that whenever the radius of one of the circle changes (ie becomes bigger or smaller than the other) the circles start moving somewhere else. i am trying to move the circles apart together (). i dont know much about vectors. i got the vector posrtion of my code from [Why circles are vibrating on collision (Canvas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43941749/why-circles-are-vibrating-on-collision-canvas)

```
CollisionHandler.pushApart = function(cell, check) {
    var x = check.x - cell.x;
    var y = check.y - cell.y;
    var distance = Math.hypot(x, y);

    var cSz = Blob.getSize(cell.mass);
    var chSz = Blob.getSize(check.mass);
    var maxDist = cSz + chSz;
    var boosting = Math.abs(cell.move.x) > 2 ||
        Math.abs(cell.move.y) > 2 ||
        Math.abs(check.move.x) > 2 ||
        Math.abs(check.move.y) > 2;


    if (distance < maxDist && !boosting) {
        x /= distance;
        y /= distance;

        var pLen = cSz / (cSz + chSz);
        var cx = cell.x + pLen * x * distance;
        var cy = cell.y + pLen * y * distance;

        cell.x += (cx - x * chSz - cell.x) * animationConstant;
        cell.y += (cy - y * chSz - cell.y) * animationConstant;
        check.x += (cx + x * cSz - check.x) * animationConstant;
        check.y += (cy + y * cSz - check.y) * animationConstant;

        /*var targetX = check.x - maxDistance * x;
        var targetY = check.y - maxDistance * y;
        cell.x += (targetX - cell.x) * animationConstant;
        cell.y += (targetY - cell.y) * animationConstant;*/
    }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>this is my clone of agar.io.</title>
 <style>
  body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas></canvas>
 <script>
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var width = innerWidth;
  var height = innerHeight;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  var blobsFood = [];
  var blobsVirus = [];
  var blobsEject = [];
  var blobsPlayer = [];
  function getRandom(n) {
   return Math.random() * n;
  };
  var gameWidth = 10000;
  var gameHeight = 10000;
  var massFood = 5;

  var animationConstant = 0.2;
  var maxSplit = 64;

  function Blob(x, y, mass, hue) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.mass = mass;
   this._mass = mass;
   this.hue = hue;
   this.time = Date.now();
   this.move = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    angle: 0
   };
  };

  Blob.getSize = function(mass) {
   return Math.sqrt(mass * 100);
  };
  Blob.getSpeed = function(mass) {
      return 15 * 1.6/Math.pow(mass, 0.32);
  };
  Blob.getBoostSpeed = function(mass) {
      return 15 * 2.6 * Math.pow(mass, 0.0122);
  };

  Blob.prototype.boostMove = function() {
   this.x += this.move.x;
   this.y += this.move.y;
   this.move.x *= 0.95;
   this.move.y *= 0.95;
  };
  Blob.prototype.getAngle = function() {
   return this.move.angle;
  };
  Blob.prototype.draw = function() {
   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);

   ctx.beginPath();
   this._mass += (this.mass - this._mass) * animationConstant;
   ctx.arc(0, 0, Blob.getSize(this._mass), 0, Math.PI * 2);
   ctx.closePath();

   ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + this.hue + ", 100%, 60%)";
   ctx.strokeStyle = "hsl(" + this.hue + ", 100%, 50%)";
   ctx.lineWidth = 5;

   ctx.fill();
   ctx.stroke();
   ctx.restore();
  };

  Blob.prototype.onEaten = function(eater) {
   // For virus and other cells
  };
  Blob.prototype.onEat = function(prey) {
   this.mass += prey.mass;
  };

  function Virus() {
   this.x = Math.random() * gameWidth;
   this.y = Math.random() * gameWidth;
   this.mass = 100;
   this._mass = 100;
   this.maxMass = 150;
   this.hue = Math.random() * 360;
  };

  Virus.prototype = new Blob();
  Virus.prototype.onEat = function(prey) {
   this.mass += prey.mass;
   if(this.mass >= this.maxMass) {
    shootVirus(this, prey.getAngle());
   }
  };
  Virus.prototype.onEaten = function(eater) {
   var numSplits = maxSplit - blobsPlayer.length;
   if(numSplits <= 0)
    return;

      var massLeft = eater.mass;
         var splitAmount = 1;
         var smallMass = 50;
         while(massLeft > 0) {
             splitAmount *= 2;
             massLeft = eater.mass - splitAmount * 30;
         };

         var splitMass = eater.mass/splitAmount;
         for(var i = 0; i < Math.min(splitAmount, numSplits); i++) {
             if (eater.mass <= smallMass) 
               break;
             var angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
             addPlayer(eater.x, eater.y, splitMass, angle, eater.hue);
             eater.mass -= splitMass;
         };
  };

  function CollisionHandler() {
   console.log("CollisionHandler started.");
  };

  CollisionHandler.eatFactor = 0.02;
  CollisionHandler.canEat = function(eater, check) {
   var x = eater.x - check.x;
   var y = eater.y - check.y;
   var distance = Math.hypot(x, y);

   var maxDistance = Blob.getSize(eater.mass + check.mass);
   var minMass = CollisionHandler.eatFactor * check.mass + check.mass;
   if(distance < maxDistance && eater.mass > minMass) {
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  };
  CollisionHandler.pushApart = function(cell, check) {
   var x = check.x - cell.x;
   var y = check.y - cell.y;
   var distance = Math.hypot(x, y);

   var cSz = Blob.getSize(cell.mass);
      var chSz = Blob.getSize(check.mass);
      var maxDist = cSz + chSz;
   var boosting = Math.abs(cell.move.x) > 2 || 
          Math.abs(cell.move.y) > 2 || 
       Math.abs(check.move.x) > 2 || 
       Math.abs(check.move.y) > 2;
      

   if(distance < maxDist && !boosting) {
    x /= distance;
    y /= distance;

    var pLen = cSz / (cSz + chSz); 
    var cx = cell.x + pLen * x * distance; 
    var cy = cell.y + pLen * y * distance;

    cell.x += (cx - x * chSz - cell.x) * animationConstant;
    cell.y += (cy - y * chSz - cell.y) * animationConstant;     
    check.x += (cx + x * cSz - check.x) * animationConstant;
    check.y += (cy + y * cSz - check.y) * animationConstant;      
    
    /*var targetX = check.x - maxDistance * x;
    var targetY = check.y - maxDistance * y;
    cell.x += (targetX - cell.x) * animationConstant;
    cell.y += (targetY - cell.y) * animationConstant;*/
   }
  };



  function addFood(n) {
   for(var i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
    var blob = new Blob(
     getRandom(gameWidth), 
     getRandom(gameHeight),
     massFood, 
     getRandom(360)
    );
    blobsFood.push(blob);
   };
   console.log(blobsFood.length);
  };



  var massVirus = 80;
  var massVirusMax = 120;
  function addVirus(n) {
   for(var i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
    var blob = new Virus();
    blobsVirus.push(blob);
   };
   console.log(blobsVirus.length);
  };



  var massEject = 10;
  function addEject(blob) {
   if(blob.mass < 20)
    return;

   blob.mass -= massEject;
   var angle = getMouseAngle(blob.x, blob.y);
   var r = Blob.getSize(blob.mass);
   var blob = new Blob(
    blob.x + Math.cos(angle) * r,
    blob.y + Math.sin(angle) * r,
    massEject,
    blob.hue
   );

   blob.move.x = Math.cos(angle) * 30;
   blob.move.y = Math.sin(angle) * 30;
   blob.move.angle = angle;

   blobsEject.push(blob);
  }; 


  function addPlayer(x, y, mass, angle, hue) {
   var moveX = Math.cos(angle) * Blob.getBoostSpeed(mass);
   var moveY = Math.sin(angle) * Blob.getBoostSpeed(mass);
   var blob = new Blob(x, y, mass, hue);
   blob.move.x = moveX;
   blob.move.y = moveY;
   blob.move.angle = angle;

   blobsPlayer.push(blob);
  };



  var mouseX = 0;
  var mouseY = 0;
  var cameraX = 0;
  var cameraY = 0;
  var _cameraX = 0;
  var _cameraY = 0;
  var zoom = 1;
  var _zoom = 1;
  function updateCamera() {
   var x = 0;
   var y = 0;
   var m = 0;
   var len = blobsPlayer.length;
   blobsPlayer.forEach(function(blob) {
    x += blob.x;
    y += blob.y;
    m += Blob.getSize(blob.mass);
   });
   cameraX = x/len;
   cameraY = y/len;
   zoom = 1/(Math.sqrt(m)/Math.log(m));
  };


  document.onmousemove = function(evt) {
   mouseX = evt.clientX;
   mouseY = evt.clientY;
  };



  document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
   var key = evt.keyCode;
   if(key == 32) {
    var len = blobsPlayer.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     var blob = blobsPlayer[i];
     splitPlayerBlob(blob);
    };
   }
   if(key == 87) {
    var len = blobsPlayer.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     var blob = blobsPlayer[i];
     addEject(blob);
    };
   }
  };
  function getMouseAngle(x, y) {
   var x = mouseX - width/2 + (cameraX - x) * zoom;
   var y = mouseY - height/2 + (cameraY - y) * zoom;
   return Math.atan2(y, x);
  };
  function splitPlayerBlob(blob) {
   var numSplits = 16 - blobsPlayer.length;
   if(numSplits <= 0) return;
   if(blob.mass >= 20) {
    blob.mass /= 2;
    var angle = getMouseAngle(blob.x, blob.y);
    addPlayer(blob.x, blob.y, blob.mass, angle, blob.hue);
   }
  };
  function mouseMovePlayer() {
   blobsPlayer.forEach(function(blob) {
    var angle = getMouseAngle(blob.x, blob.y);
    var speed = Blob.getSpeed(blob.mass);
    var x = mouseX - width/2 + (cameraX - blob.x) * zoom;
    var y = mouseY - height/2 + (cameraY - blob.y) * zoom;
    // blob.x += Math.cos(angle) * speed * Math.min(1, Math.pow(x/toRadius(blob.mass), 2));
    // blob.y += Math.sin(angle) * speed * Math.min(1, Math.pow(y/toRadius(blob.mass), 2));
    blob.x += Math.cos(angle) * speed;
    blob.y += Math.sin(angle) * speed;
   });
  };
  function movePlayer() {
   blobsPlayer.forEach(function(blob) {
    blob.boostMove();
   });
  };
  function moveEject() {
   blobsEject.forEach(function(blob) {
    blob.boostMove();
   });
  };
  function separateEject() {
   blobsEject.forEach(function(a, i) {
    blobsEject.forEach(function(b, j) {
     if(i == j)
      return;
     CollisionHandler.pushApart(a, b);
    });
   });
  };
  function separatePlayer() {
   blobsPlayer.forEach(function(a, i) {
    blobsPlayer.forEach(function(b, j) {
     if(i == j)
      return;
     var ref1 = a;
     var ref2 = b;
     CollisionHandler.pushApart(ref1, ref2);
    });
   });
  };
  function eatFood() {
   blobsPlayer.forEach(function(player) {
    blobsFood.forEach(function(food, i) {
     if(CollisionHandler.canEat(player, food)) {
      player.onEat(food);
      blobsFood.splice(i, 1);
     }
    });
   });
  };
  function eatEject() {
   blobsPlayer.forEach(function(player) {
    blobsEject.forEach(function(eject, i) {
     if(CollisionHandler.canEat(player, eject)) {
      player.onEat(eject);
      blobsEject.splice(i, 1);
     }
    });
   });
   blobsVirus.forEach(function(virus) {
    blobsEject.forEach(function(eject, i) {
     if(CollisionHandler.canEat(virus, eject)) {
      virus.onEat(eject);
      blobsEject.splice(i, 1);
     }
    });
   });
  };
  function shootVirus(virus, angle) {
   virus.mass = massVirus;
   var speed = Blob.getSpeed(massVirus);
   var blob = new Blob(virus.x, virus.y, massVirus, virus.hue);
   var x = Math.cos(angle) * 30;
   var y = Math.sin(angle) * 30;
   blob.move.x = x;
   blob.move.y = y;
   blob.move.angle = angle;

   blobsVirus.push(blob);
  };
  function moveVirus() {
   blobsVirus.forEach(function(blob) {
    blob.x += blob.move.x;
    blob.y += blob.move.y;
    blob.move.x *= 0.95;
    blob.move.y *= 0.95;
   });
  };
  function separateVirus() {
   blobsVirus.forEach(function(a, i) {
    blobsVirus.forEach(function(b, j) {
     if(i == j)
      return;
     CollisionHandler.pushApart(a, b);
    });
   });
  };
  function eatVirus() {
   blobsPlayer.forEach(function(player) {
    blobsVirus.forEach(function(virus, i) {
     if(CollisionHandler.canEat(player, virus)) {
      player.onEat(virus);
      virus.onEaten(player);
      blobsVirus.splice(i, 1);
     }
    });
   });
  };
  var baseTime = 10000;
  function canCombine(player) {
   var t = Math.floor(baseTime + (0.02 * player.mass));
   var now = Date.now() - player.time;
   return t < now;
  };
  function combinePlayer() {
   blobsPlayer.forEach(function(a, i) {
    blobsPlayer.forEach(function(b, j) {
     if(i == j) 
      return;
     var x = a.x - b.x;
     var y = a.y - b.y;
     var d = Math.hypot(x, y);
     var r = Blob.getSize(a.mass + b.mass);
     if(d < r && canCombine(a) && canCombine(b)) {
      if(a.mass > b.mass) {
       a.mass += b.mass;
       blobsPlayer.splice(j, 1);
      } else {
       b.mass += a.mass;
       blobsPlayer.splice(i, 1);
      }
     }
    });
   });
  };
  function updateGame() {
   movePlayer();
   mouseMovePlayer();
   separatePlayer();
   combinePlayer();
   moveEject();
   separateEject();
   moveVirus();
   separateVirus();
   eatFood();
   eatEject();
   eatVirus();
   updateCamera();
  };
  function drawGame() {
   clearCanvas();
   ctx.save();
   _zoom += (zoom - _zoom) * 0.1;
   _cameraX += (cameraX - _cameraX) * 0.1;
   _cameraY += (cameraY - _cameraY) * 0.1;
   ctx.translate(-_cameraX * _zoom + width/2, -_cameraY * _zoom + height/2);
   ctx.scale(_zoom, _zoom);
    drawAllBlobs();
   ctx.restore();
  };
  function clearCanvas() {
   ctx.fillStyle = "white";
   ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  };
  function drawAllBlobs() {
   var blobs = blobsFood
      .concat(blobsEject)
      .concat(blobsVirus)
      .concat(blobsPlayer);
   var blobs = blobs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.mass - b.mass;
   });
   blobs.forEach(function(blob) {
    blob.draw();
   });
  };
  function loop() {
   updateGame();
   drawGame();
   requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  };
  addFood(300);
  addVirus(15);
  addPlayer(0, 0, 3000, 0, 45)
  loop();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please put the full code in the question? Thanks.

Comment: i have posted a link to my full code

Comment: You already generated a downvote and three close votes. I am trying to help you. Links are not enough. I am under a firewall and I cannot access JSBin or JSFiddle. `:(`

Comment: i posted the full code

Comment: you should probably copy the code to some other html file. here its not showing the output properly

Comment: Sure thanks for the heads up. Will check now... Would like to try it out.

Comment: Wow, this is cool. I am technically playing with it. Looks awesome.

Comment: thanks. but do try for a solution